# using flex grow for creating tournmanet brackets

Tags: html, css, vue.js, flexbox, flex-grow

I am creating a tournmanet bracket with vue, and I am using this code as start point: https://codepen.io/aronduby/pen/qliuj but I am using a v-for for generating the brackets

```
  <ul v-for="j in jTotal>
    <div v-for="i in iTotal"
      v-if="!loading && matriz[j-1][i-1]"
      class="test"
     >

      <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>

      <li class="game game-top winner">person 1 <span>79</span></li>

      <li class="game game-spacer" >&nbsp;</li>

      <li class="game game-bottom ">person 2 <span>48</span></li>

      <li class="spacer">&nbsp;</li>

  </div>
</ul>
```

But as I have this div wrapping the li, I lost the flex-grow property that is being used in the example because I generate the structure

```
<ul>
  <div>
    <li>
```

So I would like to know if there is how I keep the property grow wrapping the 5 li that make up a game.

Thanks

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Template-v-for

Comment: Thanks! It worked just perfectly!